# Open an URL in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, url, media-player

I am trying to open an URL with androids MediaPlayer Class by using:

```
MediaPlayer.create(pContext, Uri.parse(m_sUrl));
```

i have allready replaced all the Spaces in m_sUrl String with %20 by using:

```
m_sUrl = m_sUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
```

But the MediaPlayer.Create Method return null to me. So there seems still to be something wrong by parsing the m_sUrl String.

Thats the URL string i am trying to stream:

http://www.se.hs-heilbronn.de/~poneu/files/musik/oeffentlich/2007-03-10/01%20-%20L.v.%20Beethoven-%20Ouvertüre%20Nr.%203%20zur%20Oper%20-Leonore-%20op.%2072a.mp3

so as you can see, it seems to be the ü character. Anyone know what i have to use in an valid url for ä ö ü ß and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)** and you have to keep in mind to encode only unsafe character:

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("depeche mode", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

in the exemple that i mentioned below the unsafe character is the space that will be transformed to %20

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) instead of manually replacing instances of single characters.

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(m_sUrl) gives me this:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.se.hs-heilbronn.de%2F%7Eponeu%2Ffiles%2Fmusik%2Foeffentlich%2F2007-03-10%2F01+-+L.v.+Beethoven-+Ouvert%C3%BCre+Nr.+3+zur+Oper+-Leonore-+op.+72a.mp3

and this doesent even work in the browser.

Comment: you need to do only the argument portion of the url, see @K_Anas answer.